# Lucene: Is it safe to remove all locks in its source code since I only use one single thread?

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to build a Lucene demo, the whole project only uses one single thread to write and another thread to read.

I want to reduce any possible cost inside Lucene, so I wonder if it is safe to remove all lock acquisition?

e.g.

in `IndexWriter`: `writeLock = lockDir.obtainLock(WRITE_LOCK_NAME);`

in `SimpleFSDirectory`: `this(path, FSLockFactory.getDefault());`

Comment: If you're using the HotSpot VM, it may be taking care of that for you: "*The server compiler might eliminate synchronization blocks (lock elision) if it determines that an object is thread local. For example, methods of classes such as StringBuffer and Vector are synchronized because they can be accessed by different threads. However, in most scenarios, they are used in a thread local manner. In cases where the usage is thread local, the compiler might optimize and remove the synchronization blocks.*"

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do that. If you have a single thread, you won't notice any overhead for obtaining locks. Program CPU cycles and IO staff takes much more time than staff you want to optimize.